# Using TensorFlow Lite in an Android Projec

Tags: nlp

You're saying you want to convert the model found at https://github.com/ukairia777/finance_sentiment_corpus/blob/main/BERT_sentiment_analysis_kor.ipynb into TensorFlow Lite..

How can I convert the model available on GitHub to TensorFlow Lite? It's a BERT model for sentiment analysis (positive, negative, neutral).

```py
# Function to convert to TensorFlow Lite
def convert_to_tflite(model, tokenizer, max_seq_len, train_X, train_y):
    # Model compilation
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Model training
    model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=2, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping])

    # Convert to TensorFlow Lite
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
    tflite_model = converter.convert()

    # Save TensorFlow Lite model
    tflite_file_path = '/content/bert_lite_model.tflite'
    with open(tflite_file_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(tflite_model)

    return tflite_file_path

# Attempted this approach but failed (couldn't read the model in Android...)
tflite_model_path = convert_to_tflite(model, tokenizer, max_seq_len, train_X, train_y)
```

print(f'The path where the TensorFlow Lite model is saved: {tflite_model_path}')

Could you please guide me on how to make this model work in Android through code?
(android java)

I downloaded the model from GitHub and attempted to convert it to TensorFlow Lite

```py
# Function to convert to TensorFlow Lite
def convert_to_tflite(model, tokenizer, max_seq_len, train_X, train_y):
    # Model compilation
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Model training
    model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=2, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping])

    # Convert to TensorFlow Lite
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
    tflite_model = converter.convert()

    # Save TensorFlow Lite model
    tflite_file_path = '/content/bert_lite_model.tflite'
    with open(tflite_file_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(tflite_model)

    return tflite_file_path

# Attempted this approach but failed (couldn't read the model in Android...)
tflite_model_path = convert_to_tflite(model, tokenizer, max_seq_len, train_X, train_y)

print(f'The path where the TensorFlow Lite model is saved: {tflite_model_path}')
```

android java

build.gradle (:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets {
                srcDirs 'src\\main\\assets'
            }
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        mlModelBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.7.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```